# Logstash can't parse json data without a manual newline

Tags: powershell, logstash, elastic-stack

I have a powershell script that gets internet history and I want to send the data to logstash. The function returns an array of PSObjects, which I pipe to this function:

```
function ConvertTo-logstash
{

    Begin {
        $result = ""
    }
    Process {             
            $result += $_ | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 1               
            $result += "`n"
    }
    end {
    $result.replace("\","\\")
    }

}
```

which returns data that looks like this:

```
{"Browser":"IE10/11","Category":"internethistory","Function":"inethistory","HostIP":"172.16.100.93","HostName":"wkst-7-2","LastVisitTime":"2016-08-01T16:27:13","Title":"","URL":"res://C:\\Windows\\system32\\mmcndmgr.dll/views.htm","User":"scrub","VisitCount":2}
{"Browser":"IE10/11","Category":"internethistory","Function":"inethistory","HostIP":"172.16.100.93","HostName":"wkst-7-2","LastVisitTime":"2016-08-02T14:33:26","Title":"","URL":"file:///C:/Users/scrub/Desktop/privEsc.ps1","User":"scrub","VisitCount":1}
{"Browser":"IE10/11","Category":"internethistory","Function":"inethistory","HostIP":"172.16.100.93","HostName":"wkst-7-2","LastVisitTime":"2016-08-15T10:24:38","Title":"","URL":"file:///C:/Users/scrub/Documents/template.pdf","User":"scrub","VisitCount":22}
...
```

I write this information to a file, then I send this data to logstash through a socket connection.  The issue is that logstash chokes on this data, stating that the json is invalid and the index field "Category" must be lowercase, which it is.  When I open the file in notepad and put a newline after the first entry and then send it, logstash handles it just fine.  I tried changing

```
$result += "`n"
```

to

```
$result += "`r`n"
```

as that was the change that putting the newline in notepad was doing, but no luck. Why does logstash choke on this data for seemingly no reason?

EDIT: Adding the newline is irrelevant. Simply the act of opening in notepad and saving without modifying it seems to fix the error. currently examining the binary of the files to find the difference.

Comment: Perhaps opening it, modifying it and saving it is doing more than changing the end of line character(s). File encoding? That will matter quite a lot if it's expecting ASCII encoding and you're sending UTF-16 (for example).

Comment: Show us how you output the data to the file

Comment: `get-inethistory | convertto-logstash >> "$outpath\internethistory.log"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure that the data you are collecting doesn't have any null bytes in it.  Logstash does not know what to do with an entry that has null bytes in it. Notepad  interprets null bytes as spaces and then when you save, it replaces the null bytes as spaces.  If this is the problem, then it would explain why merely saving in notepad without modifying would make it work.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The redirection operators (`>`,`>>`) defaults to the "Unicode" encoding format (UTF16-LE) - as far as I know, logstash expects input ASCII or UTF8 encoded.

Use `Set-Content` or `Out-File` instead, both support an `Encoding` parameter:

```
Get-InetHistory |ConvertTo-Logstash |Out-File internethistory.log -Encoding UTF8
```

(or if that fails)

```
Get-InetHistory |ConvertTo-Logstash |Out-File internethistory.log -Encoding ASCII
```

Comment: I did try this, and the encoding was irrelevent. I tried utf8 and ascii, and both had the same behavior as the Unicode version

Comment: That's quite interesting, looking forward to hear what binary differences you find in the file

Comment: As  suggested by @Philthecasual, the difference was all null bytes in the bad version were replaced by spaces in the good version.